# Saving String multiply data in java

Tags: java, string, list, arraylist

I searching for the best way to save data in java. 
i have two ArrayLists  with IDs and Names. Now i want it to save in the easiest and smartest way. like:

```
[index] [String ID] [String Name]
[1]["newID"]["Peter]
```

The idea behind it is, for example i have the Name "Peter" so i know the index and so on i get the ID. 
Incoming data "Peter" got index 1 and ID "newID"

So whats the best way to  implement that. 3-D ArrayLists, Vectors I'm not sure, Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using a POJO ?

```
public class DataBean implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = ...; 
  private long index;
  private String id;
  private String name;

  // add accessor methods
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Why not make a Person class?

```
public class Person {
    int index;
    String id;
    String name;
}
```

And then if you want to have lots of these, use a Collection, such as a `Set<Person>` or a `List<Person>`.

Good luck.

Comment: yeah, i already did that. i find no different way but its working :) thanks anyway

Comment: the next step is to make all the Person fields `private` and add getters and setters (x3)